# Case in Where Clause SQL (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I want to filter a query in the Where Statement. I want to compare IDs with 'IN' but only if an input has value. 
If this text comes empty I don't want to compare. Prevent the error query

EXAMPLE:

```
StringProductIDs = ''



WHERE
    ({Issue}.[ServiceRequestId] IN (@StringServiceRequestIDs)) 
    AND ({ServiceRequest}.[Id] IN (@StringServiceRequestIDs))
    AND ({Product}.[Id] IN (@StringProductIDs) OR @StringProductIDs = '')   /* Is this one that i want to prevent*/
    AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM {Sprint}.[CompleteDate]) = @Month
    AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM {Sprint}.[CompleteDate]) = @Year
```

In this case, I just want to filter things.id if the value passed as a parameter has value. If it comes empty I don't want to compare and avoid the 'AND' line

Or try another approach:). There is a way to run a query only if this input has value? If it has no value, it returns nothing. If the input has value run normally –

Many thanks

Comment: What is `@input`? That is invalid in Oracle

Comment: Those column names with the dreaded square brackets will most definitely not work with Oracle. This looks more like SQL Server's T-SQL.

Comment: This is Outsystems syntax. Then there is the mapping for Oracle database.

Answer (score 0):

You need `OR` :

```
WHERE  (things.active = 1 AND things.state = 2) AND
       (things.id IN (@INPUT) OR @INPUT IS NULL);
```

Comment: I edit the question. 
I am using OutSystems with Oracle Database. Got a error ORA - 00936

Comment: Error - ORA-00936

Comment: Try another approach:). There is a way to run a query only if this input has value?
If it has no value, it returns nothing. If the input has value run normally